# Performance issues with algorithm for calculating the average of an array in .NET

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance

The following code creates an average array of 200,000 arrays each with 512 elements.

```
void Main()
{
    double[] avg = new double[512];
    int start = System.Environment.TickCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < avg.Length; j++)
        {
            // The `i` in `i-avg[j]` is a dummy for the measured variable.
            avg[j] = avg[j] + (i - avg[j])/(i + 1);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.TickCount-start);
}
```

The reason for the iterative average is to avoid overflow when summing the values of 200,000 arrays.

In the real world, the 200,000 arrays are DFT's which are generated in 250 ms using the FFTW library. I am a little surprised that on my system calculating the average array takes about 500-600 ms (on average) i.e. iteration and a few flops takes 2-3 times longer that doing FFT.

Is there a way to speed it up or accomplish the same result using a different (faster) way in .NET, or do I have to switch languages for increased speed?

Comment: you can declare loopcounter i type as double. Each time while we are performing operation .NET internally type casts. We can save this cost of this operation.

Comment: Not sure, but try with Parallel.For and see if it helps.

Comment: If you remove TickCount, it will be twice as fast.

Comment: Division is extremely slow, like 10-30x slower than an addition. Maybe you can use a fast average for batches of 10 numbers and only use the slower iterative avg formula for those batches.

Answer (score 3):

You'll save a little bit by unrolling the inner loop by a divisor of 512. Also I'm not sure I understand what the i loop is for, as it stands the (i+1) can be pre-calculated and replaced with a multiplication. Is there a way to apply the same optimization in your real-world case, or are you doing that just to improve the accuracy of the timing?

```
        for (double i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
        {
            var inv_i_plus_1 = 1.0 / (i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < avg.Length; )
            {
                // The `i` in `i-avg[j]` is a dummy for the measured variable.
                avg[j] = avg[j] + (i - avg[j]) * inv_i_plus_1; j++;
                avg[j] = avg[j] + (i - avg[j]) * inv_i_plus_1; j++;
                avg[j] = avg[j] + (i - avg[j]) * inv_i_plus_1; j++;
                avg[j] = avg[j] + (i - avg[j]) * inv_i_plus_1; j++;
                avg[j] = avg[j] + (i - avg[j]) * inv_i_plus_1; j++;
                avg[j] = avg[j] + (i - avg[j]) * inv_i_plus_1; j++;
                avg[j] = avg[j] + (i - avg[j]) * inv_i_plus_1; j++;
                avg[j] = avg[j] + (i - avg[j]) * inv_i_plus_1; j++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The `i` loop iterates through each of the 200,000 arrays and the `j` loop trough each value of the `i`-th array. Your optimization suggestions are applicable in the real world.

Comment: I'd also have a look into the work done to enable SIMD extensions to C# i.e. the MSDN [documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/07/the-jit-finally-proposed-jit-and-simd-are-getting-married.aspx) and [samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/SIMD-Sample-f2c8c35a), the [Dr Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/64-bit-simd-code-from-c/240168851) and numerous other [web tutorials](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2014/04/04/155858.aspx). These have the potential to increase your performance by a factor of 4!

Comment: @kasperhj I had removed the `j++` from the inner `for` statement, so the last one is most definitely needed. If you wish to point out what you believe to be bugs in other people's code then please add a comment so that it can be vetted first, don't just go and edit it yourself.

Comment: Sorry. Agreed. I had c/p'ed the original loop.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
avg[j] + (i - avg[j]) / (i + 1)
```

after simplifying becomes

```
(avg[j] + 1) * i / (i + 1)
```

As we can see, `i / (i + 1)` has nothing in common with `j`, so we can precalculate it outside of the inner loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
{
    double k = i;
    k = k / (k + 1);
    for (int j = 0; j < avg.Length; j++)
    {
        avg[j] = (avg[j] + 1) * k;
    }
}
```

The final code is about 4 to 6 times faster than the original.

Comment: Well, `i-avg[j]` is in the real world something like `dft[i]-avg[j]` which I attempted to account for in the code comment. So I think the first simplification won't hold.

Comment: Bad luck then:( Still some (different) simplification can be made if `dft[i]` is **really** using `i` and not `j`. Why don't you show the exact  case.

Comment: It was just to have some code that compiled. It should probably be a bit more specific.

Comment: Nevermind. I've did some additional tests, the key point is replacing the division by pre calculated multiplication factor (like in @Mark Feldman's answer), just doing that the time goes from 0.46s to ~0.01s. So the credits go to Mark. Unrolling the inner loop doesn't seem to give a noticeable perf gain.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason must be the division in the inner loop.

You may sacrifice a little of accuracy and do a straight summation. There is no risk of overflow with doubles.

If by any chance the values are sorted in increasing or decreasing order (or close to that), summing in increasing order will preserve good accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the division to a reciprocal multiplication and then hoist the reciprocal calculation out of the loop:

```
void Main()
{
    double[] avg = new double[512];
    int start = System.Environment.TickCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
    {
        double di = (double)i;
        double r = 1/(di + 1);

        for (int j = 0; j < avg.Length; j++)
        {
            // The `i` in `i-avg[j]` is a dummy for the measured variable.
            avg[j] = avg[j] + (di - avg[j]) * r;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.TickCount-start);
}
```